# Multiple PayPal accounts linked to ONE installation of Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, woocommerce

**My issue:** The client has 12 locations, each location is a different corporation hence a different PayPal account per business. By default woocommerce only supports one email to be entered to process the payment. The goal is to use one installation of wordpress / woocommerce then direct the user to the PayPal account associated with the location they have selected upon checkout.

**My Theory / Attempt:** originally I thought of implementing this feature by setting up a variation so the user can select a location which will then pass a parameter to the URL. The parameter would later be used within the PHP to overwrite the default email.

**My Problem:** I am having trouble with overwriting the default email that is entered within the admin settings, I cant seem to locate this email in the database. I am assuming the file pertaining this modification is located at: **wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/gateways/paypal** but would prefer doing this the wordpress way vs editing core files, for obvious reasons. After doing some research I have found the following action shown below, but this is for the proceed to checkout button, I am looking to interact with the proceed to PayPal button. I am fluent in PHP but not the best with WordPress development. I would think this is a popular issue since majority of franchises would deal with such a scenario, but I am unpleasantly  surprised on the amount of information regarding this topic. If someone could point me in the right direction of conquering this task it would be greatly appreciated!

```
remove_action('woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout','woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout', 20);

add_action('woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'change_url_to_checkout', 20);

function change_url_to_checkout(){
        $extra_url = 'put_your_extra_page_url_here';
        ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $extra_url; ?>" class="checkout-button button alt wc-forward"><?php _e( 'Proceed to Checkout', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
        <?php   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see two functions to be written here.

1. To alter the order data when an order is created. This is where we save the email needed.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta' );
function woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    $email = 'paypal@location1.com';
    // do something here as to use the right email.
    // you have $order_id.
    // can be used as:
    // $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    // $order->get_billing_address_1() to get the address to check order address.
    // or use $_POST['location'] if ever you posted some data.
    update_post_meta( $order_id, '_alternative_paypal_email', $email );
}
```

2. Then use `woocommerce_paypal_args` to alter the args that is being passed to paypal.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_paypal_args', 'woocommerce_paypal_args', 10, 2 );
function woocommerce_paypal_args( $paypal_args, $order ) {
    $email = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_alternative_paypal_email', true );
    if ( !empty( $email ) ) {
        $paypal_args['business'] = $email;
    }
    return $paypal_args;
}
```

To summarize, this is just an example. But these two hooks is enough to get what you need.

Comment: Where you use '_alternative_paypal_email', have you created this field? Or does it exist in the order info?

Comment: Did this solution work for you? I am considering doing the same thing, but I wonder if PayPal allows using one set of API credentials to send payments to different paypal (email) accounts that are not linked in paypal?